# Magento 2.4.2 Installation Giving 404 issue

Tags: magento2.4.2

I am trying to install Magento2.4.2 . My system requirements seems fine. Installed PHP7.4 , Mysql 10, Elastic search 7.

And also I have ran this command first:

1. sudo composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento2/
2. bin/magento setup:install 
   --base-url=http://localhost/magento2 
   --db-host=localhost 
   --db-name=m242 
   --db-user=sammy 
   --db-password=Admin@123 
   --admin-firstname=admin 
   --admin-lastname=admin 
   --admin-email=admin@admin.com 
   --admin-user=admin 
   --admin-password=reset@123 
   --language=en_US 
   --currency=USD 
   --timezone=America/Chicago 
   --use-rewrites=1
3. Reindex
   4.deploy
   5.compile
   6.upgrade
   7.cache clean
4. permisson

And while running the site am getting the 404 error issue.

http://localhost/magento2

can some one please help me to get rid of this issue..

Thanks,

Comment: Try to change the htaccess on /app folder or delete that to run the project on localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that your webserver serves the requests from the proper location. it should be referencing the **`<magento_proj_root>/pub` folder as Document Root.**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html

Details [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/331271/upgrade-magento-2-4-1-ee-to-magento-2-4-2-ee-return-404/331328#331328) as I discussed with someone else who had the same issue.

Comment: I tried the below link. It worked for me.https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html

Comment: magento 2.4 doesn't have the index.php file in the root folder. It's only in pub/ folder.

Comment: i would suggest that it is best if the setup is done with the requests served from /pub folder and not from the project root in order to increase the security of the website.