# Error 404 on Magento 2.4.2 on Localhost

Tags: magento2, error, installation, 404, apache2

I have set up a localhost installation of Magento 2.4.2 community edition, now I am getting this error: `404 Not Found.`

I've got elasticsearch installed, a mysql database created but I can't even access the mainpage of magento 2.4.2.

I have magento set up on `/var/www/html/magento/` and this is my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` configuration:

```sh
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
#Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# The directory where shm and other runtime files will be stored.
#

DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>

# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

To install I used composer and then I ran:

```
sudo bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://local.magento2.com" --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento2 --db-user=root --db-password=(password) --admin-firstname=Name --admin-lastname=Surname --admin-email=example@email.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=EUR --timezone=UTC --use-rewrites=1 --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=localhost --elasticsearch-port=9200
```

This is my `/etc/hosts/` config:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   pcportatilrafael
127.0.0.1   local.magento2.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

These are my `/var/www/html/magento` contents:

```bash
total 1784
drwxrwxrwx  4 www-data www-data   4096 mar  3 22:30 app
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data    150 mar  3 22:27 auth.json.sample
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data   4096 mar  3 22:27 bin
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data 766543 mar  3 22:27 CHANGELOG.md
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   2634 jan  7 21:59 composer.json
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data 952379 mar  3 22:27 composer.lock
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data    650 mar  3 22:27 COPYING.txt
drwxrwxrwx  4 www-data www-data   4096 mar  3 22:27 dev
drwxrwxrwx  4 www-data www-data   4096 mar  3 23:19 generated
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data     55 mar  3 22:27 grunt-config.json.sample
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   2994 mar  3 22:27 Gruntfile.js.sample
drwxrwxrwx  4 www-data www-data   4096 mar  3 22:27 lib
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data  10376 mar  3 22:27 LICENSE_AFL.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data  10364 mar  3 22:27 LICENSE.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   6898 mar  3 22:27 nginx.conf.sample
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   1275 mar  3 22:27 package.json.sample
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data   4096 mar  3 22:27 phpserver
drwxrwxrwx  6 www-data www-data   4096 mar  3 22:27 pub
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data    700 mar  3 22:27 SECURITY.md
drwxrwxrwx  7 www-data www-data   4096 mar  3 22:27 setup
drwxrwxrwx  7 www-data www-data   4096 mar  3 23:19 var
drwxrwxrwx 84 www-data www-data   4096 mar  3 22:27 vendor
```

When I access `local.magento2.com` I go to the localhost apache2 page, when I access `localhost/magento` I get the 404 error... GOing to `localhost/phpmyadmin` works just fine.

What am I missing here? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrade Magento 2.4.1-ee to Magento 2.4.2-ee return 404](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/331271/upgrade-magento-2-4-1-ee-to-magento-2-4-2-ee-return-404)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the apache configuration for your specific magento domain. To create it, you create a file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` named after your domain followed by .conf.
In your case: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/local.magento2.com.conf`

In that file, you have to set some values:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerName local.magento2.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento
  <Directory /var/www/html/magento/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

To activate the config use the command:

```
sudo a2ensite local.magento2.com.conf
```

To deactivate the config use:

```
sudo a2dissite local.magento2.com.conf
```

I am not sure, if you have to restart apache - but it wouldnt harm anything at this point ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Had to make a small ajustment tho, I changed AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All

Comment: I will edit my answer, so others can see that, too

Comment: Don't know it's a hack or what but worked for me, +1.

Comment: for Centos8: https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/install-magento-2-4-on-centos-8/

Answer (score 2):

Actually, we've had a similar problem after upgrade, though there were NO changes in nginx configuration.

Magento removed the `index.php` file from the main folder as such we're getting 404 on all other pages aside the homepage.

For the time being I've copied the file from `pub/` into root folder and it works.

Not a perfect solution, I'll probably have to debug it later why is happening like that.

Answer (score 1):

Definetely you're missing the .htaccess