# Magento 2.4.2 404 not found

Tags: 404, magento2.4.4

I have just successfully installed newly released Magento 2.4.2 on my local server(WAMP64) but it gives 404 when try to access frontned or backend.

Can someone please help me to fix this out?

Comment: Check this answer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/331306/51810

Answer (score 0):

Check that your webserver serves the requests from the proper location. it should be referencing the **`<magento_proj_folder>/pub` folder as Document Root.**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html

Also, in this thread I offered more details on the subject [frontend and admin not working magento 2.4.2 upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332400/frontend-and-admin-not-working-magento-2-4-2-upgrade/332401#332401)

---

**LE** How to update the document root on Apache - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html#1-edit-your-server-configuration

Comment: but how can I fix 404 error on my local WAMP? 
Since frontend and admin gives 404, I never experienced this error.

Comment: you fix the error by configuring your Apacje webserver from the WAMP install to serve the requests from the pub folder instead of the magento root folder as you most likely have it now.

Comment: And how can I do that? Sorry, could you please elaborate?

Comment: I updated my answer, please check it out

Comment: I could see same answer what it was

Comment: yeah, i just added the link with the anchor to apache setings guidelines